# PowerCenter - Regular Expressions

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I got the following regular expression:

```
=([^"]*)
```

Basically I want to extract a value between = and " (example: "City=Paris", output "Paris"). But for some reason this expression wont work in PowerCenter.

You got any idea how to implement it?

Thank you
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
REG_EXTRACT('"City=Paris"','(.*\w+=)(\w+)(".*)',2)
```

This basically breaks up the string in three groups of characters and returns the second group.